# Upload image to webserver using asp fileupload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, plesk

I am developing web application in asp.net using language c# in code-behind. I am trying to upload the image by using the file upload control to my web server.
I am using using windows server that have parallels plesk 9.5.4. 
My code works perfectly in the localserver, but when I host the application, then error message like "Permission denied to httpdocs/images/xyz.jpg" shows.

I want to upload any image file to my web sever location "httpdocs://images/".
Is there any way to solve the problem? Or how can I set the permission to the directory in plesk panel? Thanks in advance.

Comment: as the error message indicates the error is due to Permission level.  give the permission it will work.

Comment: you might be having only read permission on the locaiton. change it to read and write for asp.net and network users. that wll solve the issue.

Comment: @Jodha: I cant find the group or user named asp.net or network. There is only permission for admin, or the user of the plesk. Do you have any idea, how can I add asp.net user in there?

Comment: aspnet_regiis . have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Comment: look at these links http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-setting-folder-permissions-6-of-12

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you ...
    change the permission of a folder 
by default the permission is read-only 
and the change permission read and write booth and save files on a web server

to more information visit this link....
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213407189-How-to-manage-file-directory-permissions-via-Plesk-File-Manager